How to fix warning - Unbound scanf conversion
I am trying to use the following in my code :
int val;
val = sscanf ( line_pointer, "%u,%u %s %s", &unit_id, &subprogram_id, flags.get(), slotDescriptionPtr.get() );

But getting this warning with PC-Lint
 warning 498: unbounded scanf conversion specifier '[' may result in buffer overflow
   sscanf( value + 7, "%[^/]/%[^/]/%[^\n]", low, high, delta );


Add a bound to the %s conversions — %20s or whatever the sizes of the strings are.  Note that the size you specify does not include a null terminator.  It's an exasperating inconsistency.  And there's no way to dynamically provide the size analogous to the * in printf() statements (the * in the scanf() family means something quite different).

Also, note that you show two different statements – but the fix is basically the same for the scan sets — %20[…], with the same commentary about the off-by-one size issue.


How to fix warning


Use a width in each string conversion.
  // sscanf( value + 7, "%[^/]/%[^/]/%[^\n]", low, high, delta );
  char low[100];
  char high[100];
  char delta[100];
  sscanf( value + 7, "%99[^/]/%99[^/]/%99[^\n]", low, high, delta );


Check the return value of sscanf().



Will the same solution work for something like this :
sscanf( value + 7, "%[^/]/%[^/]/%[^\n]", low, high, delta );

@abssyz Why do you not want to use a width?
